# How does Stack Overflow share a token across domains?

Tags: discussion, login, network-sites

How does Stack Overflow share token across different domains?

There is stackoverflow.com and there is stackexchange.com and its different domains, so token sharing is not easy...
How does Stack Overflow handle this when multiple domains are involved?

Is it using an iframe strategy? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Or else, does it have any other strategies?

Comment: They don't. Cookies apply to `*.<site>.com`, which means logging on on any *.stackexchange.com sites logs you on for all those sites, but not stackoverflow, superuser, askubuntu, or any other sites (if there are any) with custom names. Open the developer console in your browser (might be at F12), go to storage, find cookies. Global cookies apply to `.stackoverflow.com` , one is limited to a specific domain (not sure what it does)

Comment: I've answered that question on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other